# Problem with @misc and Mendeley

Tags: bibliographies, urls

I have problems with a web page I retrieved using Mendeley. It was automatically saved in my .bib file using the `@misc` format. However, when I cite such a web page using APA rules, it does not show the URL in my references. Do you know how I could solve this? I read I could convert the `@misc` reference to `@Online`. However, the .bib Mendeley generated file does not allow me to edit it. Here is how my reference is shown in the .bib file:

```
@misc{Kronick2014WhyStreets,
    title = {{Why Only Half of Venezuelans Are in the Streets}},
    year = {2014},
    author = {Kronick, Dorothy},
    url = {http://fivethirtyeight.com/features/why-venezeulas-middle-class-is-taking-to-the-streets/}
}
```

The APA reference is shown like this:

> Kronick, D. (2014). Why Only Half of Venezuelans Are in the Streets.

I need the URL next to it.

Thank you

Comment: Please tell us which bibliography style you employ. Also, do you employ a citation management package, such as `cite` or `natbib`?

Comment: I use these commands: \usepackage[nameinlink, capitalise, noabbrev]{cleveref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

Answer (score 1):

`apalike` is a very ancient bibliography style, as it predates the creation of the world wide web and URL strings. In consequence, `apalike` hasn't been told what to do with the `url` field. BibTeX simply ignores bib fields with unrecognized names.

What to do? You'll need to (a) load the `url` or, better still, the `xurl` package and (b) change the field

```
url = {http://fivethirtyeight.com/features/why-venezeulas-middle-class-is-taking-to-the-streets/}
```

to

```
note = {\url{http://fivethirtyeight.com/features/why-venezeulas-middle-class-is-taking-to-the-streets/}}
```

Then, perform a full recompile cycle: LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.

Alternatively, just select a more recent bib style that knows what to do with a field called `url`.

Comment: I don't know how to edit the.bib file, since I am synchronizing it with Mendeley with the overleaf premium, and it seems I cannot edit such a file. Do you know if the Chicago Style citation allows me to cite websites? What package do I need? Thank you

Comment: Instead of the `apalike` bib style (and the `natbib` citation management, right?), I suggest you use the `apacite` bib style and the `apacite` citation management package. Asidie: whenever you change the argument of `\bibliographystyle`, it's usually a good idea to delete all aux files and perform a full recompile cycle.

Comment: Since you're using Mendeley (aside: I do *not* use it), you could look into how to use the `note` field to house URL strings.

Comment: Thank you. Now I have the following problem. I added the Note to the APA references using the URL package but I have a very long URL link that does not fit the page and moves to the extreme right side of my page margin. How could I fix it? This is my reference:  @misc{Kronick2014WhyFiveThirtyEight.,
    title = {{Why Only Half of Venezuelans Are in the Streets. FiveThirtyEight.}},
    year = {2014},
    author = {Kronick, Dorothy},
    note={\url{http://fivethirtyeight.com/features/why-venezeulas-middle-class-is-taking-to-the-streets/}
}

Comment: @AntonioSmithBravo - Have you tried loading `xurl` instead of `url`? That, or loading `url` with the option `hyphens`?

Comment: Thank you! It worked.

Comment: I do not know what happened, but the \usepackage[hyphens]{url} is not working anymore. The package xurl collapses my pdf and I cannot recompile it anymore. Do you know if I should load other packages before loading xurl? Or if some packages are incompatible with xurl?

Comment: @AntonioSmithBravo - So far, you have given out exactly zero information about your TeX distribution, such as which TeX distribution you employ and when you last updated it. Hence, I'm in no position to provide a meaningful diagnosis of what might be going on. May I suggest that you post a *new query*, in which you provide a more detailed description of what you're encountering? If you use Overleaf, may I also suggest that you contact their help desk and ask for assistance? I hear that Overleaf's LaTeX support staff is top-notch.

Comment: I have solved it. I deleted the command  \parindent and then it worked. For some reason, \parindent messed up my references and made hyphens URL innefective

Comment: @AntonioSmithBravo - Nobody but you could hacve worked out that there was a stray `\parindent` somewhere in your document. (Incidentally, `\parindent` is a *length* parameter; how exactly were you trying to use this macro?)

Comment: I added \parindent in the preamble of the document, but then deleted it.

Comment: @AntonioSmithBravo - Statements such as "I added \parindent in the preamble" are not actionable. What exactly do you mean by "I added `\parindent`? Did you literally insert the instruction `\parindent` in the preamble? If not, what else did you do? If you are hoping to receive actionable advice on this site, you need to provide actionable information.